# App Cache Problems

Tags: c#, caching, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have an application in the Windows Store which actually runs fine so far. But I got some Feedback from Users who say that my application is using too much disk space. I got numbers from 1 GB to 10 GB cache storage. The Mediaelement saves some files to \AppData\Local\Packages..Application..\AC\iNetCache while streaming.

So my questions are:

**Can I somehow programmatically limit the cache storage which my Application is allowed to use?**

**Is it possible to delete the cache/appdata directly from my app?**

Comment: If somebody needs more information about something particullar I can post it if you write a comment.

Comment: What do you mean by 'cache storage'?

Comment: With cache i mean the AppData. I can't really reproduce or find this problem on my Windows 8. But a User says that the files are in a hidden Inet folder, and could be deleted easily with this CMD:  RD /S /Q C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Local\Packages\EnergySchweizAG.EnergyRadio_j028rhm5gx59m\AC\iNetCache

Comment: So is your app loading stuff from internet? Sounds like the inet folder caches loaded data from the internet.

Comment: Well my application streams from the internet. And loads covers. But actually those shouldn't be cached.

Comment: Seems to be a known issue when streaming, see: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/add56d87-e06b-4173-9774-b9f1c804be28/caching-in-acinetcache and http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/e4d0d381-ad44-40cf-992b-ca68972e162c/folder-inetcache-is-growing-up-dramatically

Comment: Thanks, this makes some things clearer. I'll Edit my Question according to this Information.